# logic error, need help can't figure out the looping logic

Tags: c++

I am a beginner coder and I need a few ideas on how my code can output the right syntax.

If I input number < 25
Outputs and extra(s) ", " because it still runs through and sees that (amount_left > 0).
How would I make it so if there doesn't exist a quarter or dime it does not output the ", "?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void compute_coins(int coin_value, int& number, int& amount_left);

int main(){
int amount_left, number;

while(amount_left > 1 || amount_left < 99){
    cout << "Enter number of cents (or zero to quit):" << endl;
    cin >> amount_left;
if (amount_left == 0){
  break;
}
else{
  cout << amount_left << " cents can be given as ";
  compute_coins(25, number, amount_left);
  if (number == 1){
    cout << "1 quarter";
  }
  else if (number > 0){
  cout << number << " quarters";
  }
  if (amount_left > 0){
    cout << ", ";
  }

  compute_coins(10, number, amount_left);
  if (number == 1){
    cout << "1 dime";
  }
  else if (number > 1){
    cout << number << " dimes";
  }
  if (amount_left > 0){
    cout << ", ";
  }
  compute_coins(1, number, amount_left);
  if (number == 1){
    cout << "1 penny";
  }
  else if (number > 1){
    cout << number << " pennies";
  }
  std:: cout << ".";
}
cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
 }
 void compute_coins(int coin_value, int& number, int& amount_left){
   number = amount_left/coin_value;
   amount_left = amount_left - (number * coin_value);
 }
```

Comment: What happens in your code for dimes and pennies when `amount_left` is zero before checking for them?

Comment: I tried putting the amount_left if else argument outside the loop. but then I get only a period at the end of each output and no commas if there is a dime or penny.

Comment: You can try that.  Step thru it in the debugger and see what goes on.

Comment: I can't find my bug still

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is that a period, and exactly one period must come after all the amounts get printed out.

Therefore, it makes no logical sense to write complicated code that tries to figure out whether it should print a period before the rest of the code, for all the remaining denominations, is done.

Just get rid of that code that prints all those periods, inside all of those awkward if/else statements.

At the very end of everything, simply execute

```
std::cout << ".";
```

No `if`s, `else`s, or buts.

Simply focus on the problem of writing out the counts of all the denominations, correctly separated by commas. Forget about the trailing period. Just focus on formatting a comma-separated list of all possible denominations. Put the trailing period out of your mind.

Then, once you get all of that working, simply append

```
std::cout << ".";
```

at the end, and call it a day. This is a 100% guaranteed, or your money back, way to end up with exactly one period at the end of your output.

Comment: What about my commas? I added std::cout << "."; at the very end, but I then I don't have any commas in between the quarters and dimes.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the code that generates commas. Those appear to be generated correctly. The existing code that produces commas is, more or less, fine, and does not need to be changed.

Comment: However, there lies another problem there when the input is >25 or >10 for it'll output a ", " between quarters and dimes even though there isn't any quarters or dimes.